# "Pivot table" term

Tags: word-meaning

I am trying to understand the term "pivot table". Unfortunately, the dictionaries I've consulted are not helpful. Does the "pivot" word refer to the fact data is "rotated" around a certain dimension? What is this term etymology?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the language around stats, not English *per se*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search will take you to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table):

> They enable a person to arrange and rearrange (or "**pivot**") statistics in order to draw attention to useful information.